# Reduce processing time of image to shape

Tags: java, collision-detection, optimization

I'm making a simple game engine using Java and have found a major issue.
To create accurate collision detection I decided to convert a transparent image into a `java.awt.geom.Area` object. However the method I'm doing this might be wrong or unoptimized.

To test it out, I tried loading an almost 200x200 (exactly 195x196) pixels image. I ran the program 5 times and this is the time it took

- 2900ms = 2s
- 2848ms = 2s
- 2999ms = 2s
- 2887ms = 2s
- 2871ms = 2s

**Average time**: 2,901ms
This isn't very good especially considering the size of the image.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public Entity(BufferedImage image) {
    this.image = image;

    entityArea = new Area();
    heightmap = new int[image.getWidth()];
        
    boolean heightFound = false;

    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {

        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                
            if((image.getRGB(x, y) & 0xFF000000) != 0) {
                entityArea.add(new Area(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1)));

                if(!heightFound) {
                    heightmap[x] = y;
                    heightFound = true;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

`heightmap` is used to refer the top pixels for an entity

Comment: You may want to consider adding areas for spans of vertically connected pixels, rather than one per pixel. For an image that's mostly a solid shape, this reduces the number of `Add(new Area...)` calls from `O(w * h)` to `O(w)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based of off bornander's [answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/210407/reduce-processing-time-of-image-to-shape/210410#210410).

*"Using the `java.awt` packages will likely be a problem when it comes to performance."* - The cause of the performance issue was `entityArea.add(new Area(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1)))`. Instead of using an `Area` object I used an array to create a transparency map as shown  below

```
public Entity(BufferedImage image) {
    this.image = image;

    transmap = new int[image.getWidth()][image.getHeight()];
    heightmap = new int[image.getWidth()];

    boolean heightFound = false;

    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {

        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {

            if((image.getRGB(x, y) & 0xFF000000) != 0) {
                    
                transmap[x][y] = 1;

                if(!heightFound) {
                    heightmap[x] = y;
                    heightFound = true;
                }
            }
            else
                transmap[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The average time when running the program 5 times changed from 2,901ms to 167ms.

Comment: Fwiw, always run a profiler on your code to help figure out what areas need improvement. Also, calls to getWidth and getHeight will always return the same values, so you could save a couple of operations there by storing the values to a local variable and use this instead; finally, depending on how the data is organized internally in image, it may be more efficient to have x as the inner loop instead of y, as this _may_ reduce the amount of cache misses.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `java.awt` packages will likely be a problem when it comes to performance.

Even if you ignore the reading of the image (which I doubt is the bottleneck here), trying to add 200 * 200 = 40,000 `Area`s into a single `Area` will run slow.

This cut down example with high-light the performance problem (note that no image is used here);

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Area entityArea = new Area();
    for(int y = 0; y < 200; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 200; ++x) {
            entityArea.add(new Area(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1)));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

For game-related code you are likely better off moving away from the `java.awt` packages and go for something optimized for gaming.

Comment: Thank you, however could you also suggest some alternatives to Area? I have a plan in my head, to store the transparency in a transparency map, and use the X and Y and check if they are colliding. It sounds really confusing and I have no idea how to explain it :D

Answer (score 0):

`.getRGB()` as a per pixel operation is slow. It can be okay if you're only sampling a few pixels, but looping over it for processing all the pixels in an image is significant performance bottleneck.

Instead of working directly on the `BufferedImage`, convert the image to an array and work with that:

```
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Or consider wrapping the conversion in a helper class as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26713029/950488):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;

public class FastRGB
{
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private boolean hasAlphaChannel;
    private int pixelLength;
    private byte[] pixels;

    FastRGB(BufferedImage image)
    {
        pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        width = image.getWidth();
        height = image.getHeight();
        hasAlphaChannel = image.getAlphaRaster() != null;
        pixelLength = 3;
        if (hasAlphaChannel)
        {
            pixelLength = 4;
        }

    }

    int getRGB(int x, int y)
    {
        int pos = (y * pixelLength * width) + (x * pixelLength);
        int argb = -16777216; // 255 alpha
        if (hasAlphaChannel)
        {
            argb = (((int) pixels[pos++] & 0xff) << 24); // alpha
        }

        argb += ((int) pixels[pos++] & 0xff); // blue
        argb += (((int) pixels[pos++] & 0xff) << 8); // green
        argb += (((int) pixels[pos++] & 0xff) << 16); // red
        return argb;
    }
}
```

Comment: There might be an issue into how im implementing it, because it does reduce the time from 2.9s to 2.8s. Moreover I found out after some debugging that the source of the large amount of time is infact `entityArea.add(new Area(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1)))` as suggested my [bornander](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/210410/174186)

Comment: @GrindingForReputation typically, memory allocation operations are slow slow, and should be avoided in tight loops.

Comment: @Vaillancourt ok thanks for letting me know

Comment: It's entirely possible; the best way to determine that is to profile your code & I should have led off with that. I was answering based on my own experience with using  `awt`'s `.getRGB()` for image processing, but as others have correctly pointed out, the first thing to do in addressing performance problems is to run the profiler.